# I can't find a way to make my code work in Svelte. The code involves an array of objects

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, sveltekit

It's a single line of code, I tried a lot of approaches, but I just can't get the result I want.

What do I want?

I want to set the attribute `loading = lazy` starting at the second item in the array. I tried a lot of things, my last temptation was to use the post ID. But does not work. Look at `else if`.

```js
<script>
    // post props
    export let post;
</script>

<!--HTML here-->
<div>
    <!-- display posts images -->
    {#if post.image}
        <!--check if image is not empty -->
        <img src={post.image.formats.medium.url} alt={post.title} />
        <!-- if id is greater than 2 add loading="lazy" -->
    {:else if post.id > 2}
        <!-- set lazy images -->
        <img src={post.image.formats.medium.url} alt={post.title} loading="lazy" />
    {:else}
        <!-- if no images then placeholder -->
        <img src="images/900x600.png" alt={post.title} loading="lazy" />
    {/if}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `post.image` is `true`, the `else if` will never be checked/executed. You could simplify this by always setting the `loading` attribute. Personally I find this easier to understand because you actually want to do the same thing for every element that has an `image`.

```
{#if post.image}
    <!--check if image is not empty -->
    <img src={post.image.formats.medium.url} alt={post.title} loading={post.id > 2 ? 'lazy' : 'eager'} />
{:else}
    <!-- if no images then placeholder -->
    <img src="images/900x600.png" alt={post.title} loading="lazy" />
{/if}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Felix! I will use this approach from now on. Thanks!